# <ul> still displaying indents with css

Tags: css

This doesn't display the indents:

```
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

This still displays the indents:

```
ol
{ 
  list-style-type:none;
}

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

The css won't apply to the element type ol?

Comment: They render identically for me. And I think you mean "indents" not "intents".

Comment: Are you talking about the indent as in the padding on the left of a list or the numbers that would appear next to each list item in an ordered list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are exactly the same. You can see it by clicking on the "Run" button below:

```html
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

```html
<!-- Don't forget the style tags -->
<style>
  ol
  { 
    list-style-type:none;
  }
</style>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to place the CSS style

```
ol
{ 
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

inside of a style tag in the head section of your webpage.

Try this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        ol
        { 
            list-style-type:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

The head section should go above your body section.